# Vector Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let ${\bf F} = \langle y, x+2y\rangle$. Calculate $\int_C {\bf F}\cdot {\rm d}{\bf r},$ where $C$ is the upper semicircle that starts at $(0,1)$ and ends at $(2,1)$.

In order to calculate this integral on the given curve, can I just let $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}+1$ and integrate normally?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** parametrize the semi-circle by ${\bf r}(t) = (1+\cos t, 1+\sin t)$, with $0<t<\pi$. Notice that ${\bf r}(0) = (2,1)$ and ${\bf r}(\pi) = (0,1)$, so we swap the limits of integration to make it go *from* $(0,1)$ *to* $(2,1)$. Write ${\rm d}{\bf r} = (-\sin t, \cos t)\,{\rm d}t$. So: $$\int_C \ {\bf F} \cdot \,{\rm d}{\bf r} = \int_{\pi}^0 (1+\sin t, 1+\cos t + 2(1+\sin t))\cdot (-\sin t, \cos t)\,{\rm d}t,$$ and go for it.

(remark: $(1+\sin t, 1+\cos t + 2(1+\sin t))$ is nothing more than ${\bf F}({\bf r}(t))$.)

---

Using the relation $y = \sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}+1$ (the center is $(1,1)$, right?) is another way of parametrizing the semi-circle, using $x$ as parameter instead of $t$. It would go like ${\bf r}(x) = (x, \sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}+1)$, with $0 < x < 2$. Then $${\rm d}{\bf r} = \left(1, \frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}\right)\,{\rm d}x,$$ and your integral would be: $$\int_C {\bf F}\cdot {\rm d}{\bf r} = \int_0^2 \left(\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}+1,x + 2(\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}+1)\right)\cdot \left(1, \frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}\right)\,{\rm d}x.$$

You should check that the result is same both ways. It is instructive.

Comment: whether ${\rm d}{\bf r}= n{\rm d} t$ ? $n$ is normal vector.